# How to set default value for missing substitution parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm calling a procedure in a script and passing variables like this:

```
@@./procedudure.sql 'var1' 'var2' 'var3'
```

In the procedure I'm using the values like this:

```
DEFINE variable1 = '&1'
DEFINE variable2 = '&2'
DEFINE variable3 = '&3'
...
insert into TABLE (id, text) values ('&varibale1', '&variable2&variable3')
```

I want to be able to call the procedure with only two parameters instead of 3 so that the last one is replaced with empty string. But when I call it like this, I get this prompt:

```
Enter value for 3:
```

I've also tried to use the parameters like this, but with the same result:

```
DEFINE variable2 = '&2' || '&3'
```

I've found this page for using prompt for missing variable, but couldn't find anywhere how to set a default value: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia#9_14

As you can see from the code, I want the last parameters to be concatenated. This should be a workaround for 240-character limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes I see it's old but... until now, unanswered!

OP, this is what you're looking for but it's not exactly simple!
I originally spotted the technique on Tanel Poder's website but not sure if he came up with it or not.

Anyway, here I'm using it to setup defaults in case warning and critical limits are not passed in to the script.

```
rem setup default values
def DEFAULT_WARN_LEVEL='97'
def DEFAULT_CRIT_LEVEL='99'

rem trick to assign values to &1 and &2 so that SQL*Plus does not ask
col warn_level new_value 1
col crit_level new_value 2
select null warn_level
,      null crit_level
from   dual
where  1=2
/

rem if values were passed in, use them, if not, use the defaults
select nvl('&1','&DEFAULT_WARN_LEVEL') warn_level
,      nvl('&2','&DEFAULT_CRIT_LEVEL') crit_level
from   dual
/
rem the values, either passed in or defaults are now in &1 and &2

rem put the values in meaningful variables
def warn_level='&1'
def crit_level='&2'
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm two jobs past writing the original question so I'm unable to test it. I'm marking your solution as accepted anyway since it looks reasonable and it might help someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you code it as `DEFINE variable3 = '&3'` in your procedure, the system thinks 3 is variable and it will always prompt for its value.

In case you want to pass a default value for 3, you should do DEFINE 3 = YOUR_VALUE_FOR_PARAM_3

Comment: &3 IS a variable. It just may be undefined.

Comment: Yes, when it is undefined and you call the proc from the command prompt, it will always prompt you to enter the value, a.k.a defining the variable. That is why defining it in the procedure will not result in the prompt and also act as a default value.

Comment: But how can I the replace the default value with actual `&3` iff it is defined?

Comment: You cannot. In your question you mentioned "I want to be able to call the procedure with only two parameters instead of 3 so that the last one is replaced with empty string."  If I understand correctly, you sometimes need to pass only two variables and sometimes three, is that right ?

Comment: yes. Exactly. If your answer contains solution to this problem, I just don't see it. Could you please write the piece of the code which does that?

Comment: You cannot do that in the prompt. I was giving you the option to only set a default value.

Comment: Thanks, but I just don't see how this can help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the example link, section 9.14, I don't see where he uses any default value. He just either asks for it, or takes the parameter. SQLPLUS always is going to ask for any &1, &2, .. he sees in your file, if it is not given as input parameter. No matter how and where you use it. It's not like in Bash, where he just replaces $1 with null, and doesn't do anything. I don't think you can disable the auto-asking in SQLPLUS.

Comment: That's not a very good news :( Any idea how to solve my problem? I know I can pass longer variables in files, but in my case it would mean a very big refactoring of the install scripts and it would be much less readable.

Comment: That's how it works. The reason it does this, is to stress the fact something is wrong with the parameters : X parameters are asked, and X-Y are given ... which is an error! What you can do in your case ? Well, consider adding a parameter too much. In casu : a fourth one. But, only when calling. If "var3" ends up being empty (that's how I understood your code works), there could be a "var4", and that could really be a default value. And if "var3" (and var1 and var2) are non-empty, var4 is just ignored. Good idea ?

Comment: Yes. That would work, but I would have to change all install scripts and force other developers to add an extra parameter. We're talking about translation packages, so it's thousands of entries. I consider this the last resort

Comment: @tvCa Even as per this case, he still needs to pass in the value for var3 (empty string as input). But as per the requirements, sometimes need to pass only two variables and sometimes three

Comment: Var4 would become var3 if var3 is empty, and thus var3 is filled. Get it ?

Comment: I see. Question should be : how come that you have multiple calls to this one, and now suddenly one call doesn't know how to pass three variables, and passes only two. Is the caller doing something wrong, or should the called program already have a function to cover a non-given, and thus default, parameter ?

Comment: It's the second thing. 99% of the time I'm good with 2 parameters. 1% of the time I need three. I guess I'll just create another procedure to cover that 1%.

Comment: @Neplan OK, thanks for that info. But, I'm interested as well, how to setup a default parameter value in SQLPLUS. I've struggled with this in the past as well.